# Continuous functions and uncountable intersections with the x-axis

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples, cantor-set

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the set $X = \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) = 0\}$ does not contain any interval (i.e. there is no interval $I \subset X$)

Of course the set $X$ can be uncountable (see [Cantor Set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)). **If we add that $f$ is continuous, is it true that X is countable?** I have been thinking about this for a while, and couldn't find any counterexamples - my intuition says the answer is yes. I tried to start a proof but really couldn't move forward.

My attempt (by contradiction): assume $X$ is uncountable. Then there exists $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $X \cap [a, b]$ is uncountable. Now, let $g$ be the restriction of $f$ to $[a, b]$. Then $g$ is uniformly continuous. I don't know what to do next, though...

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: There was a lot of nineteenth century confusion about *closed nowhere dense* sets, i.e., sets that contain no interval.  So you just need to bring your intuition up to date.  If it was hard for them then don't be surprised if it takes a little while to get it.  Too bad they didn't have StackExchange!

Comment: Absolutely! After some more months studying hopefully my intuition will be updated!

Comment: Fun fact: if $f$ is the path of a Brownian motion, then with probability 1, its zero set is uncountable and contains no intervals.  So in some sense, "almost every" continuous function has this property.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No, the conclusion is not true. Take an uncountable compact set $E$ that contains no intervals (for example, the $1/3$ Cantor set) and define

$$f(x) = \operatorname{dist}(x, E)$$

This is zero if and only if $x \in E$, and is actually Lipschitz continuous.

Comment: If you take Brouwer's construction for a space-filling curve and project it onto the x-axis and extend it periodically with period 1,you get a continuous $ f : R\to R$ which is not constant on any interval of positive length . And for any $x\in R$ and any $d>0$  the set $ \{y :|y-x|<d \land f(y)=f(x)\}$  has the cardinal of the reals.